# Driver Arraylist code: need help/guidance

Tags: java, arraylist

I don't quite understand what I'm doing and what I'm doing wrong.
Please help me to fix/finalize my code.
I am supposed to create at least 3 Student objects  with input data of your choice to initialize all the data fields of a Student object using the constructors of the classes.
Declare an ArrayList object to hold Student objects. 
Add the Student objects to the ArrayList object.
Call the toString method of the Student class to print the full name of the student followed by date of birth and the Address of each student using the Student objects in the ArrayList object.

As you can see, I have no idea how to fix this even with plenty of research. I am still in the beginner's level.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PersonDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person toString = new Person();
        Person middleInitial = new Person();
        Person lastName = new Person();
        ArrayList<String> studentList = new ArrayList<String>();

        studentList.add(new String("John", "Cassy")); 
        studentList.add(new String("Jessie", "Lucy"));
    for (String student : studentList) {
    System.out.println(student); }
    }
 } //end PersonDriver class
```

This is the original code for the driver class above: [Constructor requiring more than one for subclass super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372665/constructor-requiring-more-than-one-for-subclass-super)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: you should not open a new question for this. can't you keep asking in your previous question?

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

For each student that you instantiate, you need a `Person` class.

As the `Person Object` has a constructor like

`public Person(String lastName, String middleInitial, String firstName)`

Then to instantiate a `Person` it would look like this

Person student = new Person ("Blogg", "F", "Joe");

This can now be added to the `studentList` as

```
studentList.add (student);
```

**Now put the above into a loop**

As you have a method `getName`, you can use this as

```
for (Person std: studentList) {
    System.out.println(std.getName ()); 
}
```